# Copying and pasting between two separate programs using Automator in Mac OS X

Tags: sqlite, automation, macos, copy-paste, automator

Ok, so I have an excel spreadsheet that contains data that I would like to copy directly into an SQLite db using Menial Base, a db editor. I have tried a number of different methods such as trying to convert from .csv and .txt extensions, and nothing is working the way I need it to, so I am now resorting to Automator. From what I understand, Automator is a very powerful application, I just don't have any clue how to get it to do what I need it to, or if it's even capable of doing what I need it to. All I need it to do is copy a cell from excel, command-tab over to Base, and paste it into a cell, go back to Excel, press down and copy the next value, and then go back over into Base, press down, and paste. Then repeat and repeat and repeat a thousand times. Its not overly complicated, but I was wondering if anyone out there knows if this sort of thing is possible in automator. Would I maybe need to write my own AppleScript or something? Any thoughts or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you might go about doing the copy and paste function, but it looks as though using an AppleScript is going to be your best bet. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262841/how-to-use-automator-to-bring-window-to-front), Hope that helps